# SIGSEGV when trying to acces member of pointer after it was filled by function

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

The answer is probably stupidly easy, but I have stared at this code for quiet a while now and I simply can't find the solution.

Here is my problem. I have a pointer to a base class. Then I call a function to find an element in a vector of objects derived from that class. The pointer is passed as a parameter and filled with the found object. If I try to read a member variable of what the pointer points to I get a SIGSEV.

This is the code:

```
Base* control;
if(findControlByName("aName", control)) {
    std::cout << control->name << std::endl;  // SIGSEV happens here
}

//...

bool findControlByName(std::string name, Base* control) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < controls.size(); i++) {
        if(controls[i]->name == name) {
            control = controls[i];
            std::cout << control->name; // this works
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Pass the pointer by reference: `bool findControlByName(std::string name, Base *&control) { ... }`

Comment: I agree with @E.Moffat. The pointer in `findControlByName()` is discarded after the function returns because the pointer was passed by value. If you want to modify a pointer outside the function you need to pass it by reference.

Comment: Or change your function to return either the found pointer or a null pointer, instead of `bool`... Either approach is valid and useful...

Comment: Thanks! You saved the day! If only I had known that about two hours ago... Could you explain why that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my above comment, when you assign a value to a pointer parameter in a function, that value is local to the scope of the function, just like any other parameter that is passed by value. Assigning a value to the parameter in the scope of the function does not change it outside the scope of that function unless it is passed by reference.

An example:

```
void someFunc(int * x)
{
  static int my_static = 5;
  x = &my_static;
}
void someFunc2(int * &x)
{
  static int my_static_2 = 7;
  x = &my_static_2;
}

//somewhere else:
int * ptr;
someFunc(ptr);
//ptr is unchanged/still uninitialized
someFunc2(ptr);
//ptr points to my_static_2
```

If the signature of `someFunc` is changed to take a reference parameter, the parameter will be passed by reference instead of passed by value.